# Apache Camel, SpringBoot application in PCF results with message failures

Tags: apache-camel, cloud-foundry

We have developed Apache Camel, SpringBoot based application to read data from Oracle table and do some transformation of record and publish to Kafka topic. We are using Camel SQL component  for DB integration and implemented Split & parallel processing pattern to parallelize processing to achieve high throughput. Oracle tables are partitioned, so we are creating multiple routes, one route per table partition, to speed up the processing. We have 30 partitions in table and so created 30 routes.

```
           from(buildSelectSqlEndpoint(routeId))
                .process(new GenericEventProcessor("MessagesReceived"))
                .split(body())
                .parallelProcessing()
                .process(new GenericEventProcessor("SplitAndParallelProcessing"))
                .process(new InventoryProcessor())
                .process(new GenericEventProcessor("ConvertedToAvroFormat"))
                .to(buildKafkaProducerEndPoint(routeId));
```

I tested the application in local laptop with an adequate load and it is processing as expected. But when we deployed the application in PCF, we see some of the threads are failing. I have enabled the Camel debug log and i see below debug log line -

> Pipeline - Message exchange has failed: so breaking out of pipeline
> for exchange

Due to these thousands of messages are not published to Kafka.
From initial analysis, i figured out Camel is creating one thread for each route and based on **maxMessagePerPoll** configuration, it creates number of threads equal to **maxMessagePerPoll**.  With Split & parallel processing enabled, Camel creates additional threads equal to **maxMessagePerPoll** for Kafka publish. with this approach,  we will have hundreds of threads  created and not sure any issue with PCF. Also I tried number of routes with 2, to check the message delivery failures, and still see hundreds of failures and with only 2 routes, increases total processing time for millions of records.

Could you please let me know, how to use Apache Camel with containers like PCF? any additional configurations we need to have in PCF or Camel ?

Comment: Is there anything else in the log that indicates the root cause of the failed exchange?

Comment: No other logs which points to error